# В результате get запроса получаю ошибку CORS

Tags: jquery, ajax, apache, get, cors

Есть форма заявки, данные которой отправляю с помощью `get` запроса на [script.google.com/macros](http://script.google.com/macros)

```
$.ajax({
   url: "//script.google.com/macros/s/AKfycbxKfLr8vjVpnhSli8BfgdgdfgdfgMHeOMH3hR8odd-Mr8/exec",
   type: 'get',
   data: 'step=1&p1=' + name + '&p2=' + tel,
   success: function (data) {
      console.log("success",data);
   },
   error: function (err) {
      console.log("error",err);
   }
});
```

и в результате получаю ошибку `CORS`

> Access to XMLHttpRequest at
> 'https://script.google.com/macros/s/AKfycbxKfLr8vjVpnhSli8BfgdgdfgdfgMHeOMH3hR8odd-Mr8/exec'
> from origin 'https://test.ru' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin'
> header is present on the requested resource.

Сервер `apache` - прописываю инструкцию в `.htaccess`, но результат при этом не меняется. Как исправить?

```
<ifmodule mod_headers.c>
  Header always set Access-Control-Allow-Origin: "*"
  Header always set Access-Control-Allow-Methods "POST, GET, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS"
  Header always set Access-Control-Allow-Headers "X-Requested-With, content-type"
</ifModule>
```

Answer (score 2):

Не расценивайте это как не ответ. Отправьте запрос на свой  бек сервис который будет получать данные с google services. Раз CORS политика данного сервиса не позволяет обмениваться запросами через XMLHttpRequest который лежит в основе jQuery .ajax запроса.

Comment: так и сделал, но я не могу обработать данные внутри обработчика `php`. прописываю set_transient или `wp_mail` выбивает 500 ошибку `get` в консоли. `var_dump` ок срабатывает, `setcookie` ошибку не выбивает, но и не сохраняет данные в куки

Comment: Зачем куки? У вас должен быть по сути простой проект. Php тупо посылает .get и ответ отправляет на вронт.

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте добавить в запрос

```
      crossDomain: true,
      headers: {
          "accept": "application/json",
          "Access-Control-Allow-Origin":"*"
      }
```

Comment: слегка изменился заголовок ошибки `Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.`

Comment: Уберите headers и попробуйте снова

Comment: вернулись к тому, что было `has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.`

Comment: Тогда уберите crossDomain

Comment: `Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.`

Comment: Я вот что подумал. Cors работает только в браузере. Если с бекенда обращаться то его по идее не должно быть. Так как это google он скорее всего нормально относится если вы перед использованием его ресурсов использовали не .ajax а скажем get с сервера а не браузера

Comment: Можно попробовать `ProxyPass` в конфиге апача, или обработчик на том бакенде, который у вас там есть. В обработчике просто слать запрос на гугл, и передавать содержимое ответа обратно

Comment: Попробуйте postman для теста для начала. Он уже сразу скажет