# Как мне отправить запрос api на сайт если мешает CORS

Tags: javascript, cors

Подскажите пожалуйста как мне отправить запрос api на сайт если мешает CORS. Сайт предоставляет открытый api.

Код:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
    </head>
    <body>
        <script src="jquery-3.7.0.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        function test() {
            $.ajax({
                url: 'https://api.dellin.ru/v3/auth/login.json',
                method: 'POST',
                dataType: 'json',
                data: {
                    appkey: 'xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-7B57046BAB5F',
                    login: 'xxxxxxx@mail.ru',
                    password: 'xxxxxxxx'},
                   
                success: function (data) {
                    alert(data);
                }
            });
        };

        test();
    </script>
    </body>

</html>
```

Ошибка:
Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://api.dellin.ru/v3/auth/login.json' from origin 'http://127.0.0.1:5500' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.

Comment: Не делать этого на JS? вы же светите на весь мир своим ключем апи и данными авторизации=)

Comment: мне надо именно на js с использованием ajax, это для учебного проекта

Comment: попробуй так: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1165130/191482

Comment: не получилось, та же ошибка

Comment: Скорее всего вы не отдаете в header
"Api-Key": ваш ключ